# Thumbs up and down Javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, blogspot

i have been looking for a javascript code for the thumbs up and down system to put in my blogger site. I've seen some of the help resources, but it all required the new layout, whereas i'm using the old one.

The example of the thumbs up and down buttons are like in the following website,

http://textsfromlastnight.com/

Where people are able to flag the "Good Nights" or "Bad Nights".

I have no experienced in writing scripts, so was wondering if any people can help with the scripts, or maybe tutorials of writing those scripts would be of great help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

How about this one

http://codecanyon.net/item/thumbsup/50411

Comment: Because i don't have any scriptwriting programs, so i preferred ready-made codes, with little customization. Thanks for the help though! :)

Answer (score 1):

This works for blogger:
[Thumbs up Blogger Posts- Simple post rating for blogger](http://www.blogspot-n-blogger.co.cc/2010/02/thumbs-up-blogger-posts-simple-post.html).

You use a JScript of the [JS-Kit](http://js-kit.com/).